# stop event propagation when the event handler function takes arguments

Tags: javascript, events, handler

say you have

```
<tr onclick="viewJob(11)"> 
   <td>Job Id: 11</td>
   <td><input type="button" onclick="cancelJob(11)"/></td>
</tr>
```

When clicking the button in the TD, I want to avoid executing viewJob() on the TR. I've seen how to do this with cancelJob(e), but how do you do this when you have function parameters?

Comment: I ended up removing <tr> onclick, added a class to all the <td> except for the one containing the button, and binding a click handler for the <td> with said class.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing things can make things inaccessible to users without javascript, and those with screen readers.

I would recommend just putting in an  tag inside each  element.

Otherwise, put the onclick on the  element

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just pass the function parameters in the call after you pass in the event object?

So:

```
cancelJob(e, 11);
```

Then your js function would be:

```
function cancelJob(evt, jobId)
{
}
```

I would think this would work fine.

Though you should consider separating the js from the html but that is for a different question.

Comment: i'd like to separate the js from html, but I'm not sure how to do that since I'm iterating over a list of ids that I don't have outside of the loop building table. I could iterate over the set again to bind the onclicks, but is that an appropriate tradeoff? this must be a common need. what is the right way to decouple? I'll try doing cancelJob(e, 11).